# Import Cycles RSA 8.5

Tags: eclipse, uml, rational-rsa

I have profile A that needs to import profile B and profile B needs to import profile A.
I understand that this will be an infinite cycle although is there a work around?  Both my profiles need to reference each other.

The error is:

IRJA0273E " HwStorageManager" has one or more package import cycles involving " HwComputing."

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to merge the two profiles or create a profile C whichwould include some elements of A and B.
I have two questions...
1) Why one of your profile import another profile?
2) Are youworking on MARTE profile? I used it a lot..

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. 
Yes, I am working with the MARTE profile. I am trying to follow the specifications as closely as possible.  Not sure if merging them or creating a new profile would be ideal.  In the end though it may be the only option.

Comment: Do you know how to import only specific elements rather then the entire profile?  This way I could just import the elements needed in each and possibly avoid the import cycle.

Comment: I use a lot MARTE but with Topcase or Modelio tools not RSA... But why do you import a profile inside another one?

Comment: Sometimes a profile element has an association with another element from another profile in MARTE.  In order to do this I imported the other profile so that it can be used.  Maybe there is another way?

Comment: I believe I figured it out.  You can have nested profiles within a profile.  This solves all my problems.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are right and MARTE specification defines a "big" profile named MARTE which contains several packages each of them containing profile having nested profiles, etc.

Comment: Ya, this is the key thing.  The hard part is figuring out the capabilities of the tool and making the profiles with it that will match the expected behavior of MARTE.  Thanks for all your help @Red Beard!